# Excel VBA - Get the values of UserForm Label Caption Property

Tags: excel, vba, label, caption

I have a UserForm with labels and textboxes.  I want to loop through the Lables, get the value of their Caption property and enter that value as my column headers.

Here is a snip of my code:

```
Dim element As Control

    For Each element In WQTR_Form.Controls
        If TypeName(element) = "Label" Then
            For Each Cell In Range.Rows(1).Cells
                Cells.Value = ***Label.caption***
            Next Cell
        End If
     Next element
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to get `***Lable.Caption***`.

I tried `element.Caption` but the autocomplete list does not show Caption as a property for element because in the current context element is of the type Controls.  What I need is how to get the value of Type Label.Caption for every Label on my form.

Of course, my entire approach may be wrong!  If you have a suggestion of another way to do this please tell me.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE:***

First off thanks for all your answers.  Now, I'm having other weirdness.  I mentioned it in response to Kostas K's comment below but I want to add it to the question.  I'm getting a compile error "Variable Not Defined" for `Cell` in `For Each Cell in Range.Rows(1).Cells`.

So, being a total novice I tried adding `Dim Cell as Range`.  then I get a compile error that says the argument is not optional for `Range` in `For Each Cell in Range.Rows(1).Cells`.  Maybe that second erro is a result of adding the Dim?  Maybe that whole line of code is just wrong!????

I have thought about trying something like `For Each Cell in Range("A1":Z1)` but it that seems to defeat the purpose of `Rows(1).Cells`.

Comment: `element.Caption` is what you need. IntelliSense won't show the `.Caption` property as it does not know the type of `element` but since you limit your controls collection to just Labels, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Kostas K., I ended up adding `Dim formLabel As Label` and then `Cells.Value = formLabel.Caption` - This worked in IntelliSense.  Apparently, I have other problems in my code.  I'm getting compile errors.  first, It says that "Cell" in `For Each Cell...` is an undefined Variable.  Then I get Argument is not optional for Range in `...Range.Rows(1).Cells`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few sets of objects that inherit from a more generic object. `Control` is a generic object and several object (`TextBox`, `Label`, `ComboBox`) inherit all the properties and methods of `Control` and then add more specific properties and methods that only apply to them.

For example, every control has the properties `Top`, `Height`, `Left`, and `Width`. So MS created a class called `Control` that contained those four properties. Then they created a class called `Label` that inherited from `Control` so that `Label` would have those four properties too. Next, they added a `.Caption` property to the `Label` class - caption being specific to labels and not applicable to text boxes, list boxes, etc.

When you call `lblMyLabel.Height`, the interpreter goes through the `Label` class to the `Control` class to figure out what `Height` is. The other side of that, and the part that you're experiencing, is that when you call `ctlMyControl.Caption`, the interpreter translates that into `ctlMyControl.Object.Caption`. the `Object` property is the pathway to the `Label` class where the `Caption` property lives.

Because the interpreter figures out what kind of control it is at run time, Intellisense doesn't know at design time and can only give you the generic `Control` properties and methods.

To create column headers from labels, consider this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim lColCnt As Long

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            lColCnt = lColCnt + 1
            Sheet1.Cells(1, lColCnt).Value = ctl.Caption
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

The `Dim` statements are how you declare variables that you will be using later. The `Me` keyword refers to the Userform that I'm coding in. If your code is in a standard module, you have to load the form and refer to it by name (like in your code), but if you working in the form's class module, you can use `Me`.

Every time I encounter a label, I increment a variable and then I use the `Cells` property to write out the `Caption`. The first argument of `Cells` is the row number (1 for the header row) and the second argument is for column number, which goes up by one for every label.

Comment: Keleika, Yep, this was the ticket!  Thanks for taking the time to give that very lucid and edifying response.  Of course, I modified the code just a bit because I'm in a separate module from the UserForm and added another line for some formatting stuff (column AutoFit, cell coloring, etc.) but, in general, what you wrote is what I'm using.  Again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the control variable ie `Element.Caption`. You are wanting to loop through all "Element"'s in a Userform and check each Element's Caption.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your ***Lable.Caption*** by **element.BoundValue**
Hope it can help you.